# How to suppress Debian uname message when ssh'ing into the machine? Plus changing it to something else, if possible

Tags: ssh, uptime, motd

I would love to get rid of this `uname` message when `ssh`'ing into the Debian 9 machine:

> ```
> Linux backup-server 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64
> ```

This line I would like to keep:

> ```
> No mail.
> ```

I tried:

```
ssh -q ...
```

and setting:

> ```
> PrintLastLog no
> ```

in the:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then, I deleted the contents of this file, completely:

```
/etc/motd
```

because I don't care about it.

As a bonus, if possible I would like to see the `uptime --pretty` when `ssh`'ing into the Debian server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian 9 there are files being executed upon `ssh`'ing into the server in the directory:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/
```

All files in it will be executed upon successful `ssh`'ing if having an executable bit set.

So in this case, first list all the files in it:

```
ls -l /etc/update-motd.d/
```

and then investigating the contents with `cat`.

In my case, there was only one file named:

```
10-uname
```

with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
uname -snrvm
```

which is what I was looking for.

---

I simply changed the line:

> ```
> uname -snrvm
> ```

to:

> ```
> uptime --pretty
> ```

And renamed the script to:

```
00-uptime
```

Both the `uname` message is gone, and `uptime` gets displayed now.

---

When `ssh`'ing into the server I now see:

> ```
> up 6 days, 12 hours, 15 minutes
> No mail.
> ```

Note:

It might be wise to set immutable attribute to the file preventing it from being changed with:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/update-motd.d/00-uptime
```

Comment: When updating the relevant package, will it be changed back?

Comment: I could swear I had files of that directory changed back without asking. They are not config files.

Comment: Or might not. It was in Armbian and often they repackaged a few things. We may be both right.

Comment: The file `/etc/update-motd.d/10-uname` comes from the `base-files` package. At least in Debian 9, `dlocate -lsconf base-files` reports it **is** listed as a config file for the package manager. The files in `/etc/update-motd.d` are executed by the PAM module `pam_motd.so`. It can be removed from PAM configuration, or just configured to not run the scripts.

Comment: That should definitely protect the file from being changed, but if you deleted `/etc/update-motd.d/10-uname` completely, the next update to the `base-files` package is going to bring it back. I'd suggest replacing it with an empty file, or one with contents of your choice.

Comment: @telcoM no, removal counts as a conffile modification and is preserved on upgrades and re-installations; upgrading `base-files` won’t restore `10-uname` if it’s been removed. It’s also safe to modify `10-uname` for the same reason. If the contents of the shipped `10-uname` change *in the package*, `dpkg` will ask what it should do (keep the existing version, replace it with the new one, etc.).

Comment: @Vlastimil since `00-uptime` isn’t shipped by any package, protecting it against changes won’t help with package behaviour; the only point of `chattr +i` here would be to prevent system administrators from inadvertently changing it. No package will touch it.